# Is Slider possible in sencha charts?

Tags: javascript, sencha-charts

As my requirements is to show the slider in the line charts using sencha touch. Is it possible to show the slider in line charts?

In ExtJs examples, slider is there for Area charts and they used the slider in track mouse within interactions.But am developing application for mobiles, so for mobile we cannot have track mouse option.

I am referring to the example Area - Browser Stats, bundled with touch charts 1.0.0. In our mobile application, the requirement in line chart is that, when user tap and drags on line, it should display/update respective marker values on a slider kind of control, which moves on top of line chart along with user's finger.

1. How can i keep track of line chart marker values, when user moves/drags his finger on a line (in line chart)?
2. Is it possible to display a vertical line on x-axis (parallel to y-axis), which moves along with user's finger and displays respective marker value on top of that vertical line?

Comment: Do you still need an answer to your question ?

Comment: if possible it would be better. But as of now i kept a side about this.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood your problem, are trying to do something like : http://bl.ocks.org/2281690 ?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: No solution for this yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Latest sencha touch 2.1 comes with chart support. In that within your chart object specify this config

```
{
                type: 'iteminfo',
                listeners: [
                {
                    fn: function(me, item, panel) { //item.record.get('X') will get you the axes value

                        panel.setHtml('Text you want to display');
                    },
                    event: 'show'
                }
                ]}
```

Hope it helps... Although it wont drag as you require you can display the value when user taps on a marker...